Inertia groups of totally ramified extensions
I am trying to understand the inertia group of a local field extension and had this question. I have $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[3]{5})$ to be a totally ramified extension over $\mathbb{Q}_5$ because the polynomial $X^3-5$ is Eisenstein. I know the following:

Theorem: Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension of local fields. There exists a field $K_0$ between $K$ and $L$ such that $K_0/K$
is unramified and $L/K_0$ is totally ramified. Moreover, $[K_0 : K] = f_{L/K}, [L :
K_0] = e_{L/K}$ and $K_0/K$ is Galois.

This field $K_0$ is constructed by letting $K_0=K[\zeta_m]$, where $m=q^f-1$. In my situation, I would have $q=5, f=3$, so $K_0=\mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_{124})$. But does this mean that $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[3]{5})$ is totally ramified over both $\mathbb{Q}_5$ and $\mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_{124})$ (It just looks weird because the $124^{th}$ roots of unity seem too big to be contained in such a small extension, but maybe local fields are weird and the extension does in fact contain such large roots of unity, I don't know...)?
And the theorem implies that $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K_0)=I_{L/K} \leq \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$. But then, this means that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[3]{5})/\mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_{124}))=I_{\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[3]{5})/\mathbb{Q}} \le \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[3]{5})/\mathbb{Q}_5)$ which has order 3?? Or is $\mathbb{Q}_5(\sqrt[3]{5})=\mathbb{Q}_5(\zeta_{124})$? I'm sorry I am just terribly confused and can't make sense of the inertia group. Thank you so much in advance!

Since the extension is totally ramified, you have $f_{L/K}=1$ and $e_{L/K} = [L:K]=3$.

The cubic extension you are looking at is not Galois and so the extension has no inertia group.  And being totally ramified means the extension has residue field with size 5, so $\zeta_{124}$ is not in this cubic extension. This is why you are totally confused.

@KCd That was I think the most important part for me to have recognised. Very silly of me, thank you so much!

As stated in the comments, you actually have $e=3$ and $f=1$. Here are two ways to see this. Let $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} \newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}} K = \Q_5$ and $L = \Q_5(\sqrt[3]{5})$, and let $\pi = \sqrt[3]{5}$. Let $\ell$ and $k$ be the residue fields of $L$ and $K$, respectively, so
$$
k = \Z_5/(5) \cong \Z/(5) = \F_5
$$
and $\ell = \O_L/(\pi)$.

One way to define $e$ is by taking the discrete valuation $v_L$ of the extension field $L$, and applying it to the uniformizer of the base field $K$. In this example, we have
$$
e = v_L(5) = v_L(\pi^3) = 3 v_L(\pi) = 3 \, .
$$
Since $3 = [L : K] = e f$ by the fundamental identity, then $f = 1$.

One way to define $f$ is as the degree $[\ell : k]$ of the residue extension $\ell/k$. One can show that $\O_L = \Z_5[\pi]$, so
\begin{align*}
\ell &= \O_L/(\pi) = \frac{\Z_5[\pi]}{(\pi)} \cong \frac{\Z_5[X]/(X^3 - 5)}{(X, X^3 - 5)/(X^3-5)} \cong \frac{\Z_5[X]}{(X, X^3 - 5)} \cong \frac{\Z_5[0]}{(0^3 - 5)} \cong \frac{\Z_5}{(5)} = k \, .
\end{align*}
Thus $\ell = k$, so $f = [\ell : k] = 1$, and by the fundamental identity we have $e = 3$.



Thank you! @KCd cleared the most important part for me, but thank you for clarifying why the inertial degree must be 1 :)
